# Installed but not able to config FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, editor, config

So I'm using Windows 10, android-ndk-r12b and have installed FFMPEG 3.1.1 on my computer. 
I've checked that the installation has been successful with my command line (command prompt).

[image: ffmpeg -version]

I try to use FFMPEG with Android so I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

In this tutorial they are opening ffmpeg-2.0.1/configure file with a text editor.

I can't find the equivalent in my FFMPEG folder. Have I missed something?
Is it because I haven't any editor than Atom installed on my computer?
[image]

Comment: Your ffmpeg seems a pre-built version. The tutorial means to get the source and build it yourself.

Comment: I think, it's not easy to assemble something from sources in windows.

Answer (score 0):

@halfelf you were right. I found out how to configure the ffmpeg.

step 1. Install Cygwin64 (dos2unix)

step 2. Install android-ndk

step 3. Install ffmpeg

step 4. Extract ffmpeg-3.1.1 in android-ndk path (ret: d:\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r12b/ffmpeg-3.1.1)

step 5. Execute Cygwin64 (with Admin rights)

step 6. Then I can config build_android.sh